Can I visit Macau weekly?
Has anyone tried to travel frequently to Macau every week? Have you encountered any problems upon entry?
I have a multiple-entry visa.

What is your citizenship and where are you travelling from? You tagged the question Hong Kong, if you travel from there I don’t expect any issues unless you are spending some Chinese public authority’s money at the casinos or could be suspected of doing so.

Kuwaiti Citizen. Yes traveling from Hong Kong

What’s your status in HK?

Same, Vistor Visa

Is there a specific reason you requested a visa rather than relying on visa-free entry? In the latter case they could think you are doing visa runs to avoid the maximum allowed duration but I don’t know the specifics with an actual visa. What is the duration of your visa? How much time do you plan to spend in each territory? Hi long are you planning to stay in HK in total?

They give me a multiple visa upon arrival for thirty days. Each time I stay in Macau for only two days at the end of the week, then I leave Macau and then return the next weekend, and so on. Thanks jcaron
